# UIImageView resizes automatically on UICollectionViewCell, for no apparent reason

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to show a few images using `UICollectionView`, I already have the animation i wanted (to zoom in the "active" cell) and it works perfect when i just use the cell.
When i add an image to the cell, it works as intended on first load of the `UIViewController`, but after i scroll through it some of the `UIImages` resizes automatically, and it screw the whole thing.
Any idea why this may happen?
Here's the code i use to do the animation (custom Layout):

```
-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray* array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes in array) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect)) {
            CGFloat distance = CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect) - attributes.center.x;
            CGFloat normalizedDistance = distance / ACTIVE_DISTANCE;
            if (ABS(distance) < ACTIVE_DISTANCE) {
                CGFloat zoom = 1 + ZOOM_FACTOR*(1 - ABS(normalizedDistance));
                attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(zoom, zoom, 1.0);
                attributes.zIndex = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}


- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
{
    CGFloat offsetAdjustment = MAXFLOAT;
    CGFloat horizontalCenter = proposedContentOffset.x + (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.bounds) / 2.0);

    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(proposedContentOffset.x, 0.0, self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, self.collectionView.bounds.size.height);
    NSArray* array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:targetRect];

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* layoutAttributes in array) {
        CGFloat itemHorizontalCenter = layoutAttributes.center.x;
        if (ABS(itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalCenter) < ABS(offsetAdjustment)) {
            offsetAdjustment = itemHorizontalCenter - horizontalCenter;
        }
    }
    return CGPointMake(proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, proposedContentOffset.y);
}
```

and here's an image of how it starts and then how it ends after I scroll through it:
[image: 1st load]

[image: After scrolling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. It turns out that auto layout of iOS 6 was messing up my UI. Just had to play with the constraints and now it works.